# Ways of returning two dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary

I've tried to return two dictionaries and succeeded but I'm not pleased with it because its slow. Here is what I've done so far with Tupla: [Returning two dictionaries with Tuple from one method within another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705852/returning-two-dictionaries-with-tuple-from-one-method-within-another-class)

Here is also benchmark that supports my statement that Tupla is slow: http://www.dotnetperls.com/multiple-return-values

Considering same situation from [Returning two dictionaries with Tuple from one method within another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705852/returning-two-dictionaries-with-tuple-from-one-method-within-another-class) I've tried to go with KeyValuePair declaration instead of Tupla but I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Tuple,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>'

Here is code for that:

```
class AClass
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dictOne = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Dictionary<string, string> dictTwo = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public KeyValuePair<Dictionary<string, string>, Dictionary<string, string>> MyMethodOne()
    {
        //Adding items dictOne and dictTwo

        return new KeyValuePair<Dictionary<string, string>, Dictionary<string, string>>(dictOne, dictTwo);
    }
}
```

and

```
class BClass 
{
        AClass _ac = new AClass();

        Dictionary<string, string> dictThree = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Dictionary<string, string> dictFour = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public void MyMethodTwo()
        {
         //Here I get mentioned error
         KeyValuePair<Dictionary<string, string>, Dictionary<string, string>> calledKVP = _ac.MyMethodOne();

         Dictionary<string, string> dictThree = calledKVP.Key;
         Dictionary<string, string> dictFour = calledKVP.Value;
         //After this I loop through dictThree and dictFour and do what I need
        }
    }
```

I'm afraid that this means that it can't be done other way that "Tupla way".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us your code please. This is really straightforward unless there's something you're not telling us.

Comment: I've shared a link of my previous question and that's, in fact, my code.

Comment: Then it's really not clear what you're asking. Is returning `Tuple<Dictionary<T,U>, Dictionary<V,W>>` really too slow? Is it any faster if you define a `class MyReturnType { public Dictionary<T,U> D1 {get;set;} public Dictionary<V,W> D2 {get;set;} }` and return that instead?

Comment: I suggest that the bottle neck is elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you can use the `Tuple` class

```
public Tuple<Dictionary<T1, T2>, Dictionary<T1, T2>> GetDictionaries<T1, T2>()
{
    var dict1 = new Dictionary<T1, T2>();
    var dict2 = new Dictionary<T1, T2>();
    return Tuple.Create(dict1, dict2);
}

public void Method()
{
    var result = GetDictionaries(int, string);
    var dict1 = result.Item1;
    var dict2 = result.Item2;
}
```

Another solution, to have more than one output parameter, is to use `out` parameters

```
public void SetDictionaries(
    out Dictionary<int, string> dict1, out dictionary<int, double> dict2)
{

    dict1 = new Dictionary<int, string);
    dict2 = new Dictionary<int, double);

}

public void Method()
{
    Dictionary<int, string) dict1;
    Dictionary<int, double) dict2;

    SetDictionaries(out dict1, out dict2);
}
```

With KeyValuePair

```
public KeyValuePair<Dictionary<int, int>, Dictionary<string, string>> GetDictionaries()
{
    var dict1 = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    return new KeyValuePair<Dictionary<int, int>, Dictionary<string, string>>(dict1, dict2);
}


public void Method()
{
    var result = GetDictionaries();
    var dict1 = result.Key;
    var dict2 = result.Value;
}
```

Comment: I've used Tupla and, as I've said it was slow, I'll give it a try with out parameter.

Comment: Oh, I overead this part. Sorry. What does your `KeyValuePair` code look like? This should work, too. And (from the link you provided) this should have the best performance.

Comment: And I solved it, it was some code mistake. I've used wrong class object, object of a class with Tupla declaration. Thank you SchlaWiener!